# How To Put Image On Ball Of Brick Breaker HTML Game (Using JavaScript/HTML)

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am a beginning programmer trying to make changes to this "brick breaker" HTML game to suit my needs. I am decent with HTML & CSS however I have no knowledge of Javascript as of right now. Currently I am messing around in the javascript portion of my game and am having issues with changing the look of the ball so instead of it being a white circle it would be an image of my choosing. This is not for a project or anything, it is just something I am making for my own personal reasons and so I do not care about the "physics" of the ball much. To explain what I mean, I'm saying that I do not care much for reshaping the image to make it match the shape of the original circular shape when the image bounces off walls and bricks. I simply want to change the visuals of the white ball I currently have to be a comparably sized version of the image I want to use (the image would probably be huge so I want the image to be small like the ball is). However, if you did know how to make the ball appear circular while containing the image inside that would be awesome, but it isn't the end of the world to me.

I suspect that manipulating this line of code would do the trick although I haven't been able to figure out exactly how

```
//ball
 circle(ballX, ballY, 10, 'white')
```

Then here is my full javascript file

```
var canvas, canvasContext;

//ball variables
var ballX = 400;
var ballSpeedX = 0;
var ballY = 530;
var ballSpeedY = 0;

//paddle variables and constants
const PADDLE_WIDTH = 100;
const PADDLE_HEIGHT = 10;
const PADDLE_DIST_FROM_EDGE = 60;
var paddleX = 350;

//mouse variables;
var mouseX;
var mouseY;

//bricks variables and constants
const BRICK_WIDTH = 80;
const BRICK_HEIGHT = 20;
const BRICK_COLS = 10;
const BRICK_GAP = 2;
const BRICK_ROWS = 17;
var brickGrid = new Array(BRICK_COLS * BRICK_ROWS);
var bricksLeft = 0;

//score variables
var maximumScore = 0;
var playerScore = 0;
var attempts = 5;
var playerAttempts = attempts;
var showEndingScreen = false;

function updateMousePosition(evt) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var root = document.documentElement;

  mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
  mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;

  paddleX = mouseX - (PADDLE_WIDTH/2);

  //cheat to test the ball collision
  //                ballX = mouseX;
  //                ballY = mouseY;
  //                ballSpeedX = 4;
  //                ballSpeedY = -4;
}

function handleMouseClick(evt) {
  if(showEndingScreen) {
    playerScore = 0;
    maximumScore = 0;
    playerAttempts = attempts;
    brickReset();
    ballReset();
    showEndingScreen = false;
  }

  if(ballSpeedX == 0 && ballSpeedY == 0) {
    ballSpeedX = 0;
    ballSpeedY = -5;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  canvas = document.getElementById('gameCanvas');
  canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

  var framesPerSecond = 30;
  setInterval(updateAll, 1000/framesPerSecond);

  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', handleMouseClick);

  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', updateMousePosition);

  brickReset();
}

function updateAll() {
  moveAll();
  drawAll();
}

function ballReset() {
  if(playerAttempts <= 0) {
    showEndingScreen = true;
  }

  ballX = canvas.width/2;
  ballY = 400;

  ballSpeedX = 0;
  ballSpeedY = 5;
}

function ballMovement() {
  ballX += ballSpeedX;

  //right
  if(ballX > canvas.width && ballSpeedX > 0.0) {
    ballSpeedX *= -1;
  }

  //left
  if(ballX < 0 && ballSpeedX < 0.0) {
    ballSpeedX *= -1;
  }

  ballY += ballSpeedY;

  // bottom
  if(ballY > canvas.height) {
    playerAttempts--;
    ballReset();
  }

  // top
  if(ballY < 0 && ballSpeedY < 0.0) {
    ballSpeedY *= -1;
  }
}

function isBrickAtColRow(col, row) {
  if(col >= 0 && col < BRICK_COLS && row >= 0 && row < BRICK_ROWS) {
    var brickIndexUnderCoord = rowColToArrayIndex(col, row);
    return brickGrid[brickIndexUnderCoord];
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function ballBrickCollision() {
  var ballBrickCol = Math.floor(ballX / BRICK_WIDTH);
  var ballBrickRow = Math.floor(ballY / BRICK_HEIGHT);
  var brickIndexUnderBall = rowColToArrayIndex(ballBrickCol, ballBrickRow);

  if(ballBrickCol >= 0 && ballBrickCol < BRICK_COLS && ballBrickRow >= 0 && ballBrickRow < BRICK_ROWS) {
    if(isBrickAtColRow(ballBrickCol, ballBrickRow)) {
      brickGrid[brickIndexUnderBall] = false;
      bricksLeft--; //remove brick from the amount
      console.log(bricksLeft);
      playerScore += 10;
      console.log(playerScore);

      var previousBallX = ballX - ballSpeedX;
      var previousBallY = ballY - ballSpeedY;
      var previousBrickCol =  Math.floor(previousBallX / BRICK_WIDTH);
      var previousBrickRow = Math.floor(previousBallY / BRICK_HEIGHT);

      var bothTestsFailed = true;

      if(previousBrickCol != ballBrickCol) {
        if(isBrickAtColRow(previousBrickCol, ballBrickRow) == false) {
          ballSpeedX *= -1;
          bothTestsFailed = false;
        }
      }

      if(previousBrickRow != ballBrickRow) {
        if(isBrickAtColRow(previousBrickCol, ballBrickRow) == false) {
          ballSpeedY *= -1;
          bothTestsFailed = false;
        }
      }

      if(bothTestsFailed) { //armpit case prevents the ball from going through when both corners are covered
        ballSpeedX *= -1;
        ballSpeedY *= -1;
      }
    }
  }
}

function ballPaddleCollision() {
  var paddleTopEdgeY = canvas.height - PADDLE_DIST_FROM_EDGE;
  var paddleBottomEdgeY = paddleTopEdgeY + PADDLE_HEIGHT;
  var paddleLeftEdgeX = paddleX;
  var paddleRightEdgeX = paddleLeftEdgeX + PADDLE_WIDTH;

  if(ballY+10 > paddleTopEdgeY && //below the top of the paddle
     ballY < paddleBottomEdgeY && //above the bottom of the paddle
     ballX+10 > paddleLeftEdgeX && //right of the left side of the paddle
     ballX-10 < paddleRightEdgeX) { //left of the right side of the paddle

    ballSpeedY *= -1;

    var centerOfPaddleX = paddleX + PADDLE_WIDTH/2;
    var ballDistFromPaddleCenterX = ballX - centerOfPaddleX;
    ballSpeedX = ballDistFromPaddleCenterX * 0.35;

    if(bricksLeft == 0) {
      //                        brickReset();
      showEndingScreen = true;
    }
  }
}

function moveAll() {
  if(showEndingScreen) {
    return;
  }

  ballMovement();

  ballBrickCollision();

  ballPaddleCollision();
}

function brickReset() {
  bricksLeft = 0;

  var i;

  for(i = 0; i < 3 * BRICK_COLS; i++) {
    brickGrid[i] = false;
  }

  for(; i < BRICK_COLS * BRICK_ROWS; i++) {
    if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
      brickGrid[i] = true;
      bricksLeft++;//counts how many bricks there are on the scene and stores the value
      maximumScore += 10;
    }else {
      brickGrid[i] = false;
    }//end of else (random check)
  }//end of for
  console.log(maximumScore);
}//end of brickReset

function rowColToArrayIndex(col, row) {
  return col + row * BRICK_COLS;
}

function drawBricks() {
  for(var eachRow = 0; eachRow < BRICK_ROWS; eachRow++) {
    for(var eachCol = 0; eachCol < BRICK_COLS; eachCol++) {
      var arrayIndex = rowColToArrayIndex(eachCol, eachRow);

      if(brickGrid[arrayIndex]) {
        rect((BRICK_WIDTH*eachCol), BRICK_HEIGHT*eachRow, BRICK_WIDTH-BRICK_GAP, BRICK_HEIGHT-BRICK_GAP, 'blue');
      }//end of brick drawing if true
    }
  }//end of brick for
}//end of drawBricks

function drawAll() {
  //background
  rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 'black');

  if(showEndingScreen) {
    if(playerScore == maximumScore) {
      text("YOU WIN!", canvas.width/2, 100, 'white', 'bold 3em Arial', 'center');
      text("SCORE: " + playerScore, canvas.width/2, 250, 'white', 'bold 2em Arial', 'center');
      text("ATTEMPTS: " + playerAttempts, canvas.width/2, 400, 'white', 'bold 2em Arial', 'center');
      text("Click to continue", canvas.width/2, 550, 'white', 'bold 1.5em Arial', 'center');
    } else {
      text("YOU LOSE!", canvas.width/2, 100, 'white', 'bold 3em Arial', 'center');
      text("SCORE: " + playerScore, canvas.width/2, 250, 'white', 'bold 2em Arial', 'center');
      text("ATTEMPTS: " + playerAttempts, canvas.width/2, 400, 'white', 'bold 2em Arial', 'center');
      text("Click to continue", canvas.width/2, 550, 'white', 'bold 1.5em Arial', 'center');
    }
    return;
  }

  //ball
 circle(ballX, ballY, 10, 'white');

  //paddle
  rect(paddleX, canvas.height-PADDLE_DIST_FROM_EDGE, PADDLE_WIDTH, PADDLE_HEIGHT, 'white');

  //bricimg
  drawBricks();

  var mouseBrickCol = Math.floor(mouseX / BRICK_WIDTH);
  var mouseBrickRow = Math.floor(mouseY / BRICK_HEIGHT);
  var brickIndexUnderMouse = rowColToArrayIndex(mouseBrickCol, mouseBrickRow);

  text("Score: " + playerScore, 10, 30, 'white', 'bold 1.4em monospace', 'left');
  text("Attempts: " + playerAttempts, 673, 30, 'white', 'bold 1.4em monospace', 'left');
}

function rect(topLeftX, topLeftY, boxWidth, boxHeight, fillColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = fillColor;
  canvasContext.fillRect(topLeftX, topLeftY, boxWidth, boxHeight);
}

function circle(centerX, centerY, radius, fillColor) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = fillColor;
  canvasContext.beginPath();
  canvasContext.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, Math.PI*2, true);
  canvasContext.fill();
}

function text(showWords, textX, textY, fillColor, fontSizeStyle, textAlignment) {
  canvasContext.fillStyle = fillColor;
  canvasContext.font = fontSizeStyle;
  canvasContext.textAlign = textAlignment;
  canvasContext.fillText(showWords, textX, textY);
}
```

If someone could assist a programming newbie like me it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: circle is a javascript function.  You will need to write a new function say myImageMove().myImageMove() will need to move an image to specific coordinates

Comment: I do not know anything about JavaScript so I am still unsure of what to do. Could you provide me with an example or give me a source to where I could find the information to learn it myself?